# How to setup .NET Core app in Linux Amazon without systemd

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, .net-core, systemd

When publishing .NET Core application on Ubuntu 16.04 I need a way to run the app as a service so that it can be easily managed and automatically restarted if it fails. There is a great guide on how to do this at [Microsoft's official docs website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction). The recommended way is to use the using the `systemd` command which I have successfully used many times. However I decided to host my .NET Core projects on AWS and decided to use Amazon's Linux distribution which is based on RedHat and it does not have the `systemd` command. Here is how I created the service configuration previously on the Ubuntu servers.

Basically I am asking for an equivalent way of setting up my .NET Core app as a service and equivalent commands for managing it (start, restart, stop)

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API Application running on Ubuntu

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/aspnetcore/hellomvc
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/hellomvc/hellomvc.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10  # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**EDIT**: From the comments I have realized that what I am looking for is called a init system. I googled "Linux Amazon init" and found that the default init system used in Linux Amazon is "upstart". Here is the source where I found the answer in the [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=147081)

Comment: Does amazon linux have another init system, I'd be suprised if it didn't have either systemd or sysvinit.

Comment: I tried the sysvinit and I get an error: -bash: sysvinit: command not found. 
So I guess they don't have the sysvinit either.

Comment: I have actually googled now "Linux Amazon init" and have found that the right command to use is "upstart". I will read through a documentation to learn how to use it. I didn't realize I was looking for a init system. @derekdreery Thank you for pointing out where I should look for!

Comment: You said: 'based on RedHat and it does not have the systemd command'. Are you sure that systemd is command? did you try using "systemctl start|stop your-service" syntax?

Comment: There also is supervisord which is sort of a mini init/watchdog system that can be installed on *nix systems with different init systems and give you a similar config and control mechanism across these.